# Pandas apply on dataframe with lists as values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with two columns, column `A` a list of integers and column `B` contains integers.
My desired output is a pandas Series, whose values are lists, obtained by multiplying each element in the lists in `A` by the corresponding element in column `B`.

I tried to use `apply` but I have unexpected behaviour.

**Setup 1:**
If the lists in `A` *happens* to have max length equal to the number of columns of the DataFrame , I obtain as result a DataFrame with the original shape, as opposed to a TimeSeries

```
ts1 = pd.Series([[1, 2], [3], [4, 5]])
ts2 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])

df = pd.concat([ts1, ts2], keys=['A', 'B'], axis=1)

def foo(x):
    return [el * x['B'] for el in x['A']]

df.apply(foo, axis=1)

    A   B
0   1   2
1   6   6
2  12  15
```

**Setup 2:**
For an arbitraty length of the lists in `A` (which is my use case), `apply` fails:

```
ts1 = pd.Series([[1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6]])
ts2 = pd.Series([1, 2, 3])

df = pd.concat([ts1, ts2], keys=['A', 'B'], axis=1)

def foo(x):
    return [el * x['B'] for el in x['A']]

df.apply(foo, axis=1, reduce=False)

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (3) into shape (2)
```

I am using pandas 0.21.1 with python 3.4

I tried to play around with `broadcast` and `reduce` parameters of apply, but with no success.

Questions:

- Is there a valid syntax of apply to achieve this in my version of pandas?
- Any insight on why it is failing?
- Any better solution/approach, also using numpy or other pandas functions? My current solution doesn't feel optimal at all

Comment: Try upgrade pandas, for me in `pandas 0.23.1` it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also convert the lists to numpy arrays and use broadcasting over the two series

```
df.A.apply(np.array) * df.B
#Out:
0      [1, 2]
1         [6]
2    [12, 15]
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

For me in `pandas 0.23.1` it working nice:

```
s = df.apply(foo, axis=1)
print (s)
0          [1, 2]
1             [6]
2    [12, 15, 18]
dtype: object
```

Another solution is `zip` columns together and use list comprehenion. Unfortunately pandas does not working with lists, dictionaries in `Series` nice, most functions failed. Also `numpy` need same length of lists for convert it `2d numpy array`.

```
zipped = zip(df['A'], df['B'])
a = pd.Series([[el * j for el in i] for i, j in zipped], index=df.index)
print (a)
0          [1, 2]
1             [6]
2    [12, 15, 18]
dtype: object
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51420557/how-to-pivot-table-with-with-duplicated-index

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tuple` for a workaround. In general, Pandas doesn't work well with lists as series elements. It's not recommended practice and operations are not vectorised.

```
def foo(x):
    return tuple([i * x['B'] for i in x['A']])

df.apply(foo, axis=1).apply(list)

0      [1, 2]
1         [6]
2    [12, 15]
dtype: object
```

Or upgrade to Pandas v0.23.