# How to pivot_table with with duplicated index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df_ like this,

```
name  level  status
yes   high   open
no    high   closed
no    med    closed
yes   low    open
no    med    rejected
no    high   open
```

I am trying to create a pivot table with `index='level',columns='status', values=sum of occurances with respect to the column and index`

my code:

```
df_['temp']=df_['level'].astype(bool).astype(int)
df_.pivot(index='level',columns='status',values='temp')
```

but gives me, `ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape`

My expected output is,

```
      open closed rejected
high  2    1      0
med   0    1      1
low   1    0      0
```

Please check and tell me if there is any other easy way.

Comment: For me working `df = pd.crosstab(df['level'], df['status'])`

Comment: I did it with `df_.pivot_table(index='level',columns='status',values='temp',aggfunc='sum')`, I will check with your code @jezrael

Comment: need `size`, not `sum`

Comment: Working fine, thank you @jezrael

Comment: I am getting keyerror 'temp' if I give `df_.pivot_table(index='level',columns='status',values='temp',aggfunc='size)` why?

Comment: hmmm, there is column `temp` ? But i think it is not necessary, need `df = df_.pivot_table(index='level',columns='status',values='name',aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)`

Comment: What return `print (df_.columns.tolist())` ?

Comment: I have temp column, even your `df = df_.pivot_table(index='level',columns='status',values='name',aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)` gives `key error 'name'` but works good with `aggfunc=count` may be issue with my pandas version 0.19

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler approach would be to count the occurrences of `name`:

```
df_.pivot_table(values='name',
                index='level',
                columns='status',
                aggfunc='count',
                fill_value=0)
```